# Show status in mysql

Tags: mysql

What does this show status illustrate in mysql?

Aborted_connects and Connections  from this query: SHOW STATUS LIKE '%connect%'

Is it telling that DB connections are not closed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual is a wonderful thing:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_clients

Comment: Thanks wrikken for the helpful link.